Extend a layout instead of using include directive
After working with Laravel I am trying to use Adonis with EdgeJs. I have initiated a new project with the very last version of Adonis.
I would like to have a general layout with different content.
In Laravel I could use @layout('layout') directive combined with @section in order to extend a layout file.
I tried the same in Edge, but I see the directives as text in my browser. The only directive that works is @include('...'), which forces me to separate the layout into header and footer.
Is there a way to implement extend in Edge?
